# Goldbach Partition

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, partitions

I want to check the [Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) for a big number of $n$, but I don't know how to define this in *Mathematica*.

These are my questions:

1. Find a pair of primes $(p,q)$ for every even integer $n$, such $p+q=n$, using *Mathematica*.

and

2. How to calculate number of ways to write an even number $n$ as the sum of two primes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html), although it relies on brute-force enumeration that is unlikely to scale well.

```
f1[n_] := IntegerPartitions[n, {2}, Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ n, 1]

f2[n_] := Length @ IntegerPartitions[n, {2}, Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ n]
```

Test:

```
f1[3412]
```

> ```
> {{3407, 5}}
> ```

```
f2[3412]
```

> ```
> 43
> ```

---

#### Further experiments

Anton Antonov's recent answer surprised me, in that for larger *n* values his use of `Select[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, n], And @@ Map[PrimeQ, #] &]` is faster than `f2` above.  (In version 10.1 under Windows.)  It seems that long lists for the third parameter of `IntegerPartitions` is slow.

At the cost of increased memory consumption over `f2` but *less* memory consumption than `FrobeniusSolve` we may enumerate with `IntegerPartitions` and then filter:

```
f3[n_] := Cases[IntegerPartitions[n, {2}], {__?PrimeQ}]
```

Timings on a fairly large integer:

```
f2[1787834]          // AbsoluteTiming

Length @ f3[1787834] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {7.73629, 6643}
>
> {0.846121, 6643}
> ```

And Anton's method with the benefit of somewhat faster filtering (as used above):

```
Length @ Cases[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, 1787834], {__?PrimeQ}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.2008, 13285}
> ```

Note that in this output each solution is enumerated twice which I conjecture is the reason for the lower performance relative to `f3`.

Answer (score 8):

I propose to use [`FrobeniusSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html). It seems it gives results fairly quickly. How large is the number $n$ ?

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Select[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, 120022], And @@ Map[PrimeQ, #] &];
 ]
(* {0.340291, Null} *)

Row[{"Number of prime partitions: ", Length[res]}]
(* "Number of prime partitions: ", 1668 *)

Row[{"Sample: ", Take[SortBy[res, Abs[Subtract @@ #] &], 4]}]
(* "Sample: ", {{59981, 60041}, {60041, 59981}, {59921, 
    60101}, {60101, 59921}} *)
```

Here is another computation with a larger number:

```
In[9]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Select[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, 7878344], 
    And @@ Map[PrimeQ, #] &];
 ]  
Out[9]= {25.3882, Null}
```

Comment: Interesting variation.  I didn't expect this to be competitive with `IntegerPartitions`, but it seems that on larger numbers it is.  Also I believe that your filter can be improved; try: `AbsoluteTiming[ Cases[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, 120022], {__?PrimeQ}]; ]`

Comment: Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for pointing out the speed-up with `Cases` / `__?PrimeQ]` ! I was not aware that it can be that significant.

Answer (score 6):

As @Mr.Wizard showed, `IntegerPartitions` answers both your questions directly, and he warned that it will be slow for large $n$ because it calculates all possible partitions. There is a faster answer to your first question of finding just one partition of even $n=p+q$. Set $p\le q$, and note that usually $p$ is a small prime. The function `GoldbachTest` uses a `While` loop to check a sequence of small primes in the input list of candidates $p$. If the list is exhausted, the failure condition $\{0,0\}$ is returned.

```
GoldbachTest[n_?EvenQ, p_List] :=
   Block[{m = Length[p], i = 1},
      While[i <= m && CompositeQ[n - p[[i]]], i += 1];
      If[i > m, {0, 0}, {#, n - #} &[p[[i]]]]
]
```

Given a list $p$ of the first $k$ primes, there is a smallest even $n$ which cannot be represented as $n=p+q$, with prime $q$. The sequence begins $\{6,12,30,98,98,98,98,220,308,...\}$, which is Sloane's [A152522](http://oeis.org/A152522). This page links to a paper by Granville, Van de Lune, and te Riele, where they conjecture that the smallest prime $p$ in a Goldbach partition of even $n=p+q$ is $p<1.603*\log[n]^2 \log[\log[n]]$. They confirmed their conjecture for even $n \le 2*10^{10}$.

Thus, for an efficient test of Goldbach's conjecture from $n=n_{min}$ to $n=n_{max}$ try the following. Using `ParallelTable` will be even faster.

```
GoldbachTestList[nmin_?EvenQ, nmax_Integer] :=
   With[{p = Prime[Range[PrimePi[1.603*Log[nmax]^2 Log[Log[nmax]]]]]},
      Table[GoldbachTest[n, p], {n, nmin, nmax, 2}]
]
```

Timings show that `GoldbachTestList` is over 100 times faster than the equivalent `IntegerPartitions` formulation for $n_{max} \ge 10^5$.

Comment: That's nice, +1.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to summarize solutions to this question based on `IntegerPartitions`, `FrobeniusSolve`, and a new hybrid method.

The first method `f1[n]` based on `IntegerPartitions` finds pairs of primes summing to `n`. @Mr.Wizard found this method to be slow for long lists in the third argument. Hence, he proposed function `f3[n]` to enumerate all pairs then filter.

```
f1[n_] := IntegerPartitions[n, {2}, Prime@Range@PrimePi@n]

f3[n_] := Cases[IntegerPartitions[n, {2}], {__?PrimeQ}]
```

For reasonably large `n=1787834`, function `f3[n]` is much faster.

```
With[{n = 1787834}, {AbsoluteTiming[Length@f1[n]], AbsoluteTiming[Length@f3[n]]}]
(* {{10.5924, 6643}, {0.809354, 6643}} *)
```

The first two methods, `f4[n]` and `f5[n]`, based on `FrobeniusSolve` are from @Mr.Wizard and @AntonAntonov, respectively. The third method `f6[n]` adapts `f5[n]` by using Pick instead of Select.

```
f4[n_] := Cases[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, n], {__?PrimeQ}]

f5[n_] := Select[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, n], And @@ Map[PrimeQ, #] &]

f6[n_] := Pick[#, And @@@ PrimeQ[#]] &[FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1}, n]]
```

`Pick` is faster than `Select`, but the fastest formulation is `f4[n]` with `Cases`. The number of solutions is twice as large because both solutions `{p,q}` and `{q,p}` are returned. Since half of 1787834 is prime, there is also a solution `{p,p}` which is not duplicated.

```
With[{n = 1787834}, {
     AbsoluteTiming[Length@f4[n]], 
     AbsoluteTiming[Length@f5[n]],
     AbsoluteTiming[Length@f6[n]]}]
(* {{2.55104, 13285}, {5.35851, 13285}, {3.78575, 13285}} *)
```

The hybrid solution recognises that `FrobeniusSolve[{1,1},n]` simply returns pairs of integers `{k,n-k}` for `k=0,1,...,n`, and tests each pair for primality. Function `f7[n]` begins with a list of primes `p` about half as long as for `f1[n]`, then tests for prime `n-p`.

```
f7[n_] := Block[{p = Prime[Range[PrimePi[Quotient[n, 2]]]]}, 
             Transpose[{#, n - #} &[Pick[p, PrimeQ[n - p]]]]
          ]
```

Reversed solutions are not returned by `f7[n]`, so the count is again 6643. The timing is about 10 times faster than the best solution so far, `f3[n]`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Length@f7[1787834]]
(* {0.062481, 6643} *)
```