# I need some help with this algorithm

Tags: performance-tuning, warning-messages, prime-numbers

I'm quite new to Mathematica yet, so there's probably a lot of not-so-subtle problems (indeed the algorithm isn't even running yet). My goal with this algorithm is to input an integer $n$ and get all Goldbach partitions of all even integers > 4 up to $2n$. I'd like it to be as efficient as possible, since this is part of a bigger code, and I really want all partitions for each even. What I considered: I'm gonna input an integer $n$, and I'll return a list (of lists of 2-uples) $G$ with all partitions, wherein $G$[[0]] will give the list of all partitions of the first even > 4 and so on. Also, for efficiency sake, I'm willing to calculate only the primes between $2(n-1)$ and $2n$ each iteration, but I guess that's far from clear on what's coded there. This justifies, though, the prime list $Pr$, since I'm just appending up the new primes that happen at each iteration. So, the algorithm is to calculate the next prime (which is the 'primepi[2t]-th' prime, put it on the list, calculate the sum of all 2-combinations of the list of primes and check whether it sums up to $2t$; if so, it'll append this tuple to $G$.

```
 GTest[n_Integer] := 
    Pr = List[];  G = List[]; k = 0;
    ParallelTable[
    Append[Pr, Prime[PrimePi[2*t]]] && 
    Do[( k = Subsets[Pr, {2}][[j, 0]] + 
    Subsets[Pr, {2}][[j, 1]] ) && 
   (If[k == 2*t, Append[G, Subsets[Pr, {2}][[j]]]]),
   {j, 0, Length[Subsets[Pr, {2}] - 1]}],  {t, 3, 2*n}]
```

The error I'm getting is quite long, I'll paste just the ten last lines:

> (kernel 1) Append::normal :  Nonatomic expression expected at position
>   1 in Append[Int,366].
>
> (kernel 2) Part::partd :  Part specification {}[[0,1]] is longer than
>   depth of object.
>
> (kernel 1) Part::partd :  Part specification {}[[0,1]] is longer than
>   depth of object.
>
> (kernel 2) Append::normal :  Nonatomic expression expected at position
>   1 in Append[Int,330].
>
> (kernel 1) Append::normal :  Nonatomic expression expected at position
>   1 in Append[Int,368].
>
> (kernel 2) General::stop :  Further output of Append::normal will be
>   suppressed during this calculation.
>
> (kernel 1) General::stop :  Further output of Append::normal will be
>   suppressed during this calculation.
>
> (kernel 2) Part::partd :  Part specification {}[[0,1]] is longer than
>   depth of object.
>
> (kernel 1) Part::partd :  Part specification {}[[0,1]] is longer than
>   depth of object.
>
> (kernel 2) General::stop :  Further output of Part::partd will be
>   suppressed during this calculation.
>
> (kernel 1) General::stop :  Further output of Part::partd will be
>   suppressed during this calculation.
>
> During evaluation of In[53]:= Append::normal: Nonatomic expression
>   expected at position 1 in Append[Int,6].
>
> During evaluation of In[53]:= Append::normal: Nonatomic expression
>   expected at position 1 in Append[Int,8].
>
> During evaluation of In[53]:= Append::normal: Nonatomic expression
>   expected at position 1 in Append[Int,10].
>
> During evaluation of In[53]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   Append::normal will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: The symbol `&&` is the logical operator `And`, which means it takes as arguments statements that have to evaluate to `True` or `False`. You seem to be using it as a `CompoundExpression`, i.e. as a way to make *Mathematica* evaluate those steps in sequence. Use `;` instead. In any case, when first learning a programming language, it's a good idea to do simple things first. Take apart the pieces of your code and see if you can get them working on their own *first*, then try to put pieces together, piece-by-piece.

Comment: By the way, what is `P`? You haven't defined it in your post. Is it actually supposed to be `Pr`?

Comment: It indeed was Pr. I changed just before posting. And, yes, I was trying to use it as a CompoundExpression.
I have little experience programming, and most of it in Python. To be honest, I'm finding Mathematica quite confusing, compared to Python and R, but I haven't sat and tried to do something I really wanted yet. Until now, I explored a few built-in functions, to visualize functions, curves and networks (Manipulate is awesome to see things). This is the first time I'm determined to code something useful (and more complex), but I have experimented some coding before.

Comment: among many things `Append` returns the result of the operation, it does not modify its argument. So whatever your code is trying to do `Pr` and `G` always remain empty lists.   You might want `AppendTo`.

Comment: your function as you've defined it is actually just this `GTest[n_Integer] :=Pr = List[]; ` . The first error is because you are evaluating the rest of the code outside the function body and `Pr` is not defined.  Need to wrap it all in `(  )`

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103871/goldbach-partition) question?

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed quite new to Mathematica.  I would recommend learning that arrays are indexed 1-based rather than 0-based before leaping straight into a parallel table.  And you can't picks two things out of a list of size one.  And `P` is not the same as `Pr`.  But enough admonishment.  I'd just use the built in partitioning to do it.

```
ClearAll@GoldbachPartitions;
Attributes[GoldbachPartitions] = {Listable};
GoldbachPartitions[n_] := IntegerPartitions[2 n, {2}, Prime@Range@PrimePi[2 n]]
```

In action:

```
GoldbachPartitions@123
```

> `{{241, 5}, {239, 7}, {233, 13}, {229, 17}, {227, 19}, {223, 23}, {199, 47}, {193, 53}, {179, 67}, {173, 73}, {167, 79}, {163, 83}, {157, 89}, {149, 97}, {139, 107}, {137, 109}}`

```
GoldbachPartitions@Range[2, 10]
```

> `{{{2, 2}}, {{3, 3}}, {{5, 3}}, {{7, 3}, {5, 5}}, {{7, 5}}, {{11, 3}, {7, 7}}, {{13, 3}, {11, 5}}, {{13, 5}, {11, 7}}, {{17, 3}, {13, 7}}}`

Comment: Thanks @wxffles. Admonishments are often useful. As I've seen on another question, using IntegerPartitions won't make the code quite slower, for larger $n$? As I understood reading elsewhere, it would calculate every 2-partition and only then find those made out of prime numbers, won't it?
If that's not the case, than it's an awfully elegant solution that of yours.

Comment: @izzorts  Notice that I am using `IntegerPartitions` with three arguments.  The third argument provides the list of the integers it's allowed to use.  In this case, it's the list of primes less than $2n$.  So it should be very efficient.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.