# Goldbach's Conjecture?

Tags: list-manipulation, prime-numbers, partitions

If we have a list of even integers, how can we find partitions of size 2, then determine if the partitions are composed of prime numbers? So far, I think I would have to use `IntegerPartition` and `PrimeQ`, but I'm struggling with how to use these commands with a list. Would I have to use `Map` or something similar?? Any hints would be appreciated!!

Comment: Check [Goldbach Conjecture](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldbachConjecture.html) at Wolfram Mathworld. I suggest that the Mathematica demonstration code at [Goldbach Conjecture](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GoldbachConjecture/) will get you started.

Comment: Something like: Select[Flatten[IntegerPartitions[#, {2}] & /@ Range[4, 10], 1], 
 And @@ (PrimeQ /@ #) &]

Comment: Given even `n`, are you looking for all decompositions into a sum of two primes, or just one such?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103871/goldbach-partition). In particular, one partition can be found very fast using a bound on the smallest of the two primes.

Comment: I'll note that a single number is all that's necessary to determine an integer partition of size 2; so, for an even number `n` that you want to Goldbach-partition, you can simply enumerate the primes up through `n/2` inclusive, subtract it from `n`, and see if the result is prime. This might be a tiny bit slower, but as long as you're not working with huge numbers of numbers, it should be clearer what's happening and not affect the time too much. (I think this approach is taken in the second answer to the question linked in the comment just above me.)